# limited access to files

Tags: security, asp-classic

i read that if you want to give your users a file that nobody can access via url, you need to put it in a directory in an upper level of the domain.

on my computer it worked but when i have tried that online what i got is the domain.com and after that the folder that i needed to be 2 levels up

what is the right way to do it?

Comment: There is so much missing here I'm not sure where to start. Are you running a web host and want to give your clients/users access to a file? Or do you simply have a website and want to allow only specific web site users to access a file. These two questions have very different answers... Please provide more information on what exactly you want to do and what the context is (e.g. what do you mean by "users"). Information on your software platform would also be useful.

Comment: we have a server windows 2003 and we build websites

Comment: By "users" you mean users on your windows server, or users in the websites that it serves? I'd guess the first by your partial solution, but please be more specific... There are a few people like me who hate guessing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are the files on the server in relation to the web root?  For example, if your web root is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication\` then you'll want to put the files outside of that directory (otherwise, they're shared like any other file).  Then, in your ASP code, you'll control access to that file by reading it in the code and outputting it to users who are permitted to access it.

It sounds like you say you have that latter part working on your local machine already, is that the case?  How exactly is it failing on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it accessible by any URL from any one, then don't put it in your web server domain at all. If you want it accessible by only certain people, then you need to look into some kind of authentication / authorization technique.